# Nonetype object from loading pickle in python

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a method to save a pandas dataframe to pickle that essentially looks like the following:

```
def saveData(df, name):      
    import pickle            
    print('Saving data...')  
    output = open(name, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(df, output)  
    output.close()           
    print('Done.')
```

When I try to load the saved pickle files I get an empty object of nonetype. The method I'm using to load essentially looks like the following:

```
def loadData(name):
    import pickle
    print('Loading data...')
    target = open(name, 'rb')
    df = pickle.load(target)
    target.close()
    print('Done.')
```

Comment: How do you detect that a "None" is returned?

Comment: Works fine on my end. You should double check your `df` if it's `None`. what is `df` that you pass to `saveData`? Also, there is `df.to_pickle` and `pd.from_pickle` function.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have passed both a pandas DataFrame and python dictionary both seem to output data to file but load nothing. And I didn't know about those included functions i will try that.

Comment: Are you doing something like `data = loadData()`? You realize your function does nothing with the local variable `df`, right?

Comment: The load function does not return the loaded item.  It returns nothing at all, so it returns `None` by default.

Comment: @JohnGordon damn, stupid mistake,  left out the return line, thanks for catching this.